# Cron Job Set using WP-CLI method. Seems to be functioning. Civimail won't send. Suggestions?

Tags: civimail, cron

- Wordpress 5.8
- CiviCRM 5.38.0
- PHP 7.4.15
- System Stats say "Cron Running OK
- Last cron run at September 8th, 2021 5:30 PM."
- All extensions up to date.
- Using wp-cli method as laid out here:
- https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/
- Cron is set to run every 10 minutes.

Delivery has not yet begun for a mailing set for 1pm Pacific today (9/9/2021). In the mail log, I get this: "If the scheduled delivery date and time is past, ask the system administrator or technical support contact for your site to verify that the automated mailer task ('cron job') is running - and how frequently."

How do I get a past mailing to run? And how do I ferret out why it's not running automatically?

Comment: You didn't mention this, so just checking ... Is the 'Send Scheduled Mailings' job enabled at `Administer > System Settings > Scheduled Jobs` ?  What happens if you run that with 'Execute now'?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It works with "Execute Now." So that's good. Apparently the cron _says_ it's okay, but it's not running automatically. I'm going to attempt using the cv cli method from cron instead. Not sure the wp-cli method is functioning properly.

It's possible I've got the wrong user for "cronuser". Should that be my ssh user, or a wordpress admin?

Comment: The docs imply "CMS user" so I'm thinking a wp admin. Does it have to be an admin?

Comment: when I execute `/usr/bin/php /home/user/usr/local/bin/cv api job.execute --user=cron --cwd=/home/user/mysite.org` from ssh, I get a bunch of warnings about gravity forms. Argh.

Comment: Deactivated gravityforms, (old version anyway) and put this in cron: `*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/usr/local/bin/cv api job.execute --user=cron --cwd=/home/user/mysite.org 2>&1 | /home/user/usr/local/bin/timestamp >> /home/user/cronlog/cronlog.txt` . Seems to be running correctly. The simple log seems to confirm. I'll keep an eye on it and try a scheduled mailing again. Hopefully this will cinch it.

Comment: From the log: 
`{
    "is_error": 0,
    "version": 3,
    "count": 1,
    "values": 1
}`

Comment: Looks hopeful... If mails are sent with 'execute now' and cron is running without error there's a good chance it will work when you try another mailing.

Comment: Thanks Aidan. Unfortunately my test mailer did not run as scheduled. No errors in my cron log. Cron says it's okay in system status. Cron is running because the log adds information every ten minutes. I'm at a loss.

Comment: If you look at the joblog for 'Send Scheduled Mailings' does it show cron starting it or does it only have your 'execute now' runs?

Comment: Aidan, It's set this way:
Send Scheduled Mailings (Always) • 
Sends out scheduled CiviMail mailings • 
API Entity: job • 
API Action: process_mailing •
IT's basically set to run anytime cron runs, when I look at it in the edit window. There are no additional parameters included. When I view the jobs log specifically for mailings, it only shows the one mailing starting and completing on the 9th that we started manually. So you can see why I'm puzzled! ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ok - what does it show in the 'Enabled?' (4th) column of the scheduled jobs listing?

Comment: Aidan, holy crackers! I think that might be it. It's not enabled. So I edited the settings for "Send Scheduled Mailings," and now it says "Yes" in the 4th column. I feel you've asked me if my computer monitor is plugged in, and behold, it's not plugged in... Ha ha! Let's hope this does the trick. So embarrassed. But then, CiviCRM has a pretty steep learning curve... ;) - Most recent job log: 2021-09-13 17:50:02 - `Finished execution of Send Scheduled Mailings with result: Failure, Error message: API permission check failed for Group/get call; insufficient permission: require access CiviCRM`

Comment: Aidan, thank you so much for your help. I feel like we're making progress. Perhaps my user "cron" needs to be some sort of CiviCRM special user, not merely a wordpress user. Does this sound right?

Comment: My makeshift cronlog does not show any errors for the times where the API permission check failure is listed, so that's interesting.

Comment: I've made Cron user a WP admin. That helped. Unfortunately, I thought this was solved. It may not be. CiviCRM email job log shows as success/complete but neither I nor the other person I sent the test email to received emails. The Job list says it has executed properly. Cron log is executed properly... I'm about as puzzled as I can be.